# How to execute shell script in non blocking manner using protractor?

Tags: node.js, bash, protractor

Using steps below

1. Execute some selenium code to build an app.
2. Run the app by downloading it.

Observations:
Step 1 gets executed after step 2 since I am issuing shell commands in step 2. To avoid this, I put step 2 in afterEach block. This is working, but I don't have much flexibility and this approach is not scale-able. Any pointers on how to achieve sequential execution? I would like to run a .sh file as step 2, thus giving much more flexibility.

Comment: You could use node's `child_process` to do this probably. `spawnSync` won't return until the child process exits. Use that to run your shell script and it should do what you want. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options

Comment: some code will be much helpfull to suggest a solution ?

Comment: @damitj07 : Step 1: Do some web clicks and functions to create an app. App automatically gets downloaded to specified destination because of this:
`
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser'],
        prefs: {
            'download': {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'directory_upgrade': true,
                'default_directory': 'downloads'
            }
        }
    }
`
Step 2 can be as simple as ls -al downloads` or `chmod +x appName

Answer (score 0):

Your spec file should look something like this:

```
// step1: whatever selenium webdriver code you want to run
thisThing.click();

// step2: whatever other code you want to run, but inserted into the controlFlow queue
browser.controlFlow().execute(() => {
    // for example...
    var child_process = require('child_process');
    console.log(String(child_process.exec('ls -al downloads')));
});
```